# Loop Inside a dotnet using stament

Tags: .net, loops, using

I have this code

```
public static void AddMeter(List<string> meter)
{
    using MeterProvider meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
            .AddMeter("Meter.Errors")
            .AddMeter("Meter.Prompts")
            .AddPrometheusHttpListener(options => options.UriPrefixes = new string[] { "http://*:9184/" })
            .Build();
}
```

And What I am trying to do is adding meters (.AddMeter()) by iteration.

so something like this;

```
using MeterProvider meterProvider = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()
        foreach (var meter in meters)
        {
            .AddMeter(meter)
        }
        .AddPrometheusHttpListener(options => options.UriPrefixes = new string[] { "http://*:9184/" })
        .Build();
```

What would be the correct synax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
var builder = Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder();
foreach (var meter in meters)
{
    builder = builder.AddMeter(meter);
}
using MeterProvider meterProvider = builder
    .AddPrometheusHttpListener(options => options.UriPrefixes = new string[] { "http://*:9184/" })
    .Build();
```

Basically you just store the result of `Sdk.CreateMeterProviderBuilder()` in a variable, call `.AddMeter()` in a loop updating that variable, and then call the rest of what you need on the result of that variable.  There's nothing particularly special about the syntax of a fluid API like this, each method is simply returning the same updated object which can be stored in a variable like any other.